# how to use multiple views in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, xib, multiple-inheritance

how can we create 2 views in same `viewController`? Here is a image for reference-

[image: 2 views in same viewcontroller]

in this image there is 2 different views in single `xib` file. i have 2 different classes `viewController1` and `viewController2` with `XIB` files in my application. Together they both work good.

Clicking a `UIButton` on `viewController1` opens `viewController2` using `pushViewController` code. 
Now my client want to open `viewController2` on `viewController1` without pushing. Also `viewController2` should look transparent sothat contents of both should appear. 
Both of the classes has too much business logic and if i merge them then code will become clunky. I tried dragging `viewController2`'s view to `viewController1` from `xib` and now they both are looking simultaneously but how to move further?? Is this related to **Inheritance** where i have to implement **multiple interfaces**? 
I dont have a little bit idea of multiple interface in `Objective C`.

Can anybody help me?

I'm waiting...

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewController2 *viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
viewController2.view.frame = self.view.frame;
viewController2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:viewController2.view];
```